# How to access C# dll using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

i have a class library in c# and i added that dll as a reference to the web site and I want to access the methods which are in the class library.
when I tried accessing those methods using ActiveXobject it throwing an exception saying object cant be created

```
namespace Office
{
    public class Algebra
    {
        public double Addition(double x, double y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my method in c# class library.
and my javascript is as follows

```
(function () {
        alert("suresh");
        var myobj;
        myobj = new ActiveXObject("Office.Algebra");
        alert(myobj);
        var add = myobj.Addition(7, 6);
        alert(add);
    })();
```

Answer (score 5):

No! Don't go this way.

If you want to access server resources from the client-side, you'll need to design and implement a Web service, for example on top of REST principles, which drives you directly to [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

In summary: expose resources from the backend using a Web service and access them using [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: The first line of this answer sums up my initial reaction to this question perfectly!

Comment: @DavidWatts Hahaha, I know that everyone will experience the same reaction: "NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO INTEROP NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken in guessing, you have a dll that you want to run on the web browser (iirc, only IE). If that's the case, then you have to register the dll on the client computer ( with regsvr, regasm, depending on your dll).

But I agree with Matias, use it as last resort, for example, you have to call this dll for some legacy hardware requirement, legacy app, etc, and you've spent 3 months at least looking for another way. :p